# Other word for "financial help". Can charity be a financial "contribution"?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms, connotations

> Thank you for your donations.

1. How to change **donations** in this sentence? **Financial help**? **Contribution**?
2. What if I wanted to generalize my thanks for all kinds of helping? Could I say **gifts**?

Comment: your gift. Singular.

Comment: Why do you want to change "donations". That is, what does "donations" convey that you are trying to avoid, or what does "donations" lack that you are trying to convey. I ask because "donations" seems perfectly suited to use in the context of giving, especially to a charity. This is assuming that there are in fact multiple gifts, and so the plural form is appropriate.

Comment: +1 to sharur. This should be an answer. I'd comment that "donations" can be plural if one person gave more than one donation, or if "you" is intended to be plural and each person included in "you" gave a donation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "donation" can be anything -- furniture, clothing, services, cars, artwork, etc.  A "financial contribution" is specifically a donation of *money*.

Donations are sometimes called "gifts", albeit ones with certain conditions and sometimes benefits for the giver.

Donations are also sometimes referred to as "support" to further emphasize that you are *helping* in some way.

Any of these are acceptable:

> Thank you for your (charitable) **donation**
>
> Thank you for your (financial) **contribution**
>
> Thank you for your **gift**.
>
> Thank you for your **support**

Lastly, there are certain specific kinds of donations, which you can thank someone for if appropriate:

> **endowment**: A grant of money providing for the continuing support or maintenance of something.
>
> **grant**: a donation given for a specific purpose
>
> **bequest**: a donation given posthumously in a will

In certain limited cases you might also use something overly positive like *beneficence*, *benefaction*, or *philanthropy*, or somewhat negative like *dole* or *handout*.

Comment: But non material help cannot be a "contribution", right?

Comment: @Probably  No, "contribution" is a generic term for any kind of help.  So, services such as legal or professional advice can be considered "contributions", and in some cases have to be declared on tax forms.